# How to keep colored output using sed

Tags: sed, osx, pipe, ls, colors

I'm using the `sed` command and I want to keep colored output from the previous command. The output of `ls` is colored, but the output of sed is not. I'm using OSX.

```
ls -la | sed -En  '/Desktop/q;p'
```

Answer (score 13):

On macOS, the `ls` is not GNU `ls` and does not accept the `--color=always` option that Linux users might expect for this functionality.

In the macOS version of `ls`, the colors are controlled by [two variables](https://ss64.com/osx/ls-env.html): `$CLICOLOR` and `$CLICOLOR_FORCE`. If the former is defined, the terminal specified by `$TERM` supports color, and the output is to a terminal, then this output will be colored, much like GNU's `--color=auto` option. If the latter variable is defined as well, the final condition is dropped, behaving like GNU's `--color=always`.

So to have color passed through to `sed`, you would need something like the following:

```
CLICOLOR_FORCE=1 ls -la | sed -En '/Desktop/q;p'
```

Comment: macOS's `ls` does have the `-G` option to enable color as well, but I'm not sure how it behaves in a pipeline.

Comment: @8bittree Passing `-G` is equivalent to defining `$CLICOLOR` (and therefore not sufficient)

Answer (score 8):

I'll blindly guess that your distribution, like many, has an alias that maps `ls` to `ls --color=auto`. `ls -la --color=always | sed …` should work.

(The `auto` setting makes, broadly speaking, `ls` check if its output goes to the display or not, and only color for the display. The reason for this is that color is realized by escape sequences, i.e. invisible command characters, so a program might confuse them for part of the filename, things like that.)

Comment: The blind guess is wrong. OSX is not a Linux distribution and does not use a GNU userland